# PHP routing system for blog posts

Tags: php, database, dynamic, routes

I have managed to create a simple routing system however I'm a bit stuck on how to make it more dynamic. In this case I have got a blog post set up in my routing which is hard coded. If i click a dynamic link in my website that requires the  /views/blog/page.php how can I get the system to work out what the page_slug is and append the page_slug so that it works without hard coding the links into it?

```
switch ($request) {

    case '':
    case '/':
        require __DIR__ . '/views/index.php';
        break;
    
    case '/blog/blog-post-one':
         $_GET['page_slug'] = 'blog-post-one';
        require __DIR__ . '/views/blog/page.php';
        break;
}
```

I've added my .htaccess file below just in case

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Check this link maybe will help you: https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/

Comment: @MohcinBN Yeah that's pretty much what mine does already. It's making it more dynamic is what I was wondering.

Comment: Ahh, so you have to get some basic about object oriented programming, so you can work with GET/POST request, something like that: https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-build-a-basic-server-side-routing-system-in-php-e52e613cf241